# Modelling a full order heat exchanger in dymola modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to model the full-order model of a heat exchanger in dymola with the set of ODEs. I am new with modelica and dymola. I wanted to know how can I start and model the heat exchnger? Should I use blocks or the coding?

I tried some tutorials but I do not know hot to start to model this heat exchnager.

Comment: If you search for "HeatExchanger" in Dymola's package browser you find Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.HeatExchangerSimulation - you can use that as a starting point. Either directly or to explain what you need instead.

Comment: which fluids? what kind of heat exchanger? which level of detail? 0D, 1D,...?

Comment: Dear @HansOlsson, Thanks for your help. I have used that example, but I don't know how to implement the high-order model of the heat exchanger. After implementing the full-order model, I want to work on the reducing the order of it and further simulations.

Comment: Dear @ImkeKrueger, I was considering water and another refrigerant like R134. I was considering the shell and tube heat exchanger. I wanted to implement the full-order model of it and then study reduced order models.

Comment: This is a really challenging component... my recommendation: start from the simplest representation and add more complicated equations later on. It is hard to detect bugs in your code in a complicated model for beginners. As many people modeled components like this before, I recommend to search for open source libraries, if they cover what you need e.g. https://thermosyspro.gitlab.io/documentation/ to learn Modelica, I recommend to start with simpler models, thermofluid and two-phase fluids are one of the most complex domains in Modelica.

Comment: Dear @ImkeKrueger, thanks for the insightful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can get some insight looking in the ThermoSysPro library, which contains several heat exchanger modellings. Like @ImkeKrueger said, start from the basics, especially if you are not used to coding in modelica.

Then you should try coding your own components, such as the tube bundle, with 2 fluid ports and a thermal port, the water boxes, the tubes for conduction with 2 thermal ports and then the shellside fluid.

Start with steady-state 0D modelling, subcomponents testing procedures, and then dream bigger :)